# in iOS, animated view returns to its original state after manually calling segue

Tags: ios, animation, storyboard, state, segue

I have two View Controllers in the storyboard linked by a segue. The first View Controller does an animation where it slides an UIImage from the middle to the top of the screen and then shows a UIButton, all that works great. However, when the button gets touched I perform a segue, presenting the 2nd view controller on a modal. But as the 2nd View controller slides up the screen I can see that the UIImage returns to the middle of the screen as it was before it was animated.

This is it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.willAnimate=YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (self.willAnimate) [self animate];
}
- (void) animate{
    if (self.willAnimate){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.8];
            //hide button first
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
            self.myButton.alpha=0;
            [UIView commitAnimations];

        //move background
        CGRect imgRect = self.myImageView.frame;
        imgRect.origin.y-=200;
        self.myImageView.frame=backgroundRect;

        //restore button
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.8];
            self.myButton.alpha=1;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.willAnimate=NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)myButtonPressed {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self ];
}
```

Is this happening because the segue is loading the 1st View Controller from the storyboard? How can I transition back and forth between the View Controllers leaving the image as it was after the animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably due to auto layout. When you change a frame with auto layout on, any other action that requires the system to re-layout the views causes the frame to revert to the frame defined by the constraints. So, you should either turn off auto layout, or change the origin by modifying the layout constraints. When you use auto layout, you should never do any setting of frames, only modifying constraints.

Comment: You are right, I removed the UIImageView un UIBUtton from the storyboard and create them programatically and its all good now.